# Is this a legitimate registry key? (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

In hkey_local_machine/software/classes

I found some registry keys named msime.taiwan, msime.japan and a couple others with similar names, except with a number at the end of, so there was 4 keys altogether.  From what I know itmcoulc be associated with a thing in windows that lets you write japanese characters or whatever. I also found a macaffee page, , which seemed dated but it said the key is created by a virus named w32 virut.

Just wondering is this a legit key? I found it on another pc and both pcs show when exported to a .txt show it was last written to in 2009.

Here is the reg query for the 4 keys. (added lines to differentiate them.) (This is on Windows 7 64 bit)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Japan
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Microsoft IME (Japanese)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Japan\CLSID
    (Default)    REG_SZ    {6A91029E-AA49-471B-AEE7-7D332785660D}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Japan\CurVer
    (Default)    REG_SZ    MSIME.Japan.11


----------------------------------------------------------------

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Japan.11
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Microsoft IME (Japanese)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Japan.11\CLSID
    (Default)    REG_SZ    {6A91029E-AA49-471B-AEE7-7D332785660D}


----------------------------------------------------------------

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Taiwan\CLSID
    (Default)    REG_SZ    {F407D01A-0BCB-4591-9BD6-EA4A71DF0799}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Taiwan\CurVer
    (Default)    REG_SZ    MSIME.Taiwan.8


----------------------------------------------------------------

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Taiwan.8
    (Default)    REG_SZ    IMTCCORE

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MSIME.Taiwan.8\CLSID
    (Default)    REG_SZ    {F407D01A-0BCB-4591-9BD6-EA4A71DF0799}
```

Comment: I should add that im on windows 7 home premium and dont have any language packs, if that is related.  I found this key another home premium pc

Comment: [Looks like it is](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939398/zh-tw).

Comment: So its a legitimate key and safe to ignore?

Comment: Well that says vista but I presume its carried to windows 7?

Comment: Considering Windows 7 is based on Vista, I would say so. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), and run this command: `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\MSIME.Taiwan" /s` Then post there the full output.

Comment: Will I post the output as an image for the 4 registry keys in question?

Comment: Okay, when Ill have the output up within a few hours when I get to the pc.

Comment: Why do you care about these registry keys?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I had come across them, and just googled them with one of the first results being a macafee page saying its a key related to a type of worm.

Comment: @and31415 I have added the output for the 4 entries.

Comment: @and31415 hi would you be able to answer this as I have posted the info you have asked for?

Comment: @Keyes Well, I agree with the answer posted by Izam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These keys are for the Microsoft Input Method Editor -- A tool allows you to type characters in Asian alphabets out of combinations of latin characters. You should find them on any computer running Vista or later. As of Windows Vista, you don't need to install any special language packs to support typing these languages. The MS-IME is installed with the OS, and just needs to be activated from intl.cpl

You may also find these on XP, if you have installed support for far-east languages.

Comment: Okay, the reason I had been alarmed was from this:http://home.mcafee.com/virusinfo/virusprofile.aspx?key=2284065  apparently it says its created by this worm. Ia it saying that the data (data changed by a worm) in it or the actual key its self is malicious?

Comment: @keyes I am not aware of any mechanism by which these registry keys (even if modified by a worm) would be seriously harmful. At most I would expect it may interfere with your ability to interfere to type Japanese.

Comment: I understand that any registry key has the ability to be modified harmfully. But im just trying to figure out are these legitmate keys for a win7 home premium system (I have no language packs). When I export the registry keys as .txts, the last written time (according to tye .txt) is somewhere in 2009, and its a system that been built in 2013. Do you have these specific keys and do they have the correct data above?

Comment: @Keyes Yes these keys are on my Windows 7 machine as well. I didn't check the values at first, but I double checked, and they match yours exactly. You should find them on any Windows PC running Vista or later.

Comment: Okay, so the macafee thing must be referring to something else? Like the key being modified? I was concerned because the worm that apparently creates this (which it seems it doesnt as you have it aswell) has remote access capabilities so I was concerned. Just to double check, do you have these keys anywhere else? I found them in different hkey's in regedit. And do you use any language packs?

Comment: @keyes I have turned my Windows computer off already (I am on my mac) so I can;t search my registry. I don't have any special language packs installed. Perhaps the malware you describe creates these keys on XP machines (which don't have them by default) as a side effect of some other behavior.

Comment: I didnt have any reason to think I had malware (I had scanned with mbam and such,  and no symptoms of the said malware)  but it was that the macfee page said it was a registry "element" created by a worm. But we can say its legit since you have  identical keys and another system I have has the same.  If you could confirm you have these keys in different hkey registry directories I would be very grateful.  I ask of this as I originally found the keys in a different hkey directory, I can't remember if it was current users or not, but if you could check I could compare it to what I find, thanks.